# How to hide the "internet tethering" banner atop of my view?

Tags: ios, iphone

I do not want to resize or change the position of the components on my view when the "internet tethering" banner is shown atop of the view. Is there any programatic way to hide this banner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you could resize the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]`, or change your window's `windowLevel` but my guess is that unless you set your app to hide the StatusBar you'll always get this. Maybe even then.

I've never seen this banner, but I guess it's the same type of thing as when calls occur?

Comment: For your reference Max - http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3301/3635644427_4ee974d53b.jpg

Comment: Yeah it's the same, just blue instead of green.

Comment: Thanks man. I finally decide to hide the status bar without trying other things. I wanted to nail this issue once for all.